# Min-height 100% issue, div only 100% of the displayed window, won't extend

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my layout: I've done what I normally do to get the main content div to fill 100% of the page and extend even further if there's more content than the height of the viewable page.

The issue is, it fills 100% of the viewable page, but if it extends past that point (adds a scroll bar) then the content div and wrapper div don't extend to take up the rest of the page. I've searched around for a few possibilities as to why it's doing this but I haven't found anything.

You can view the page at http://www.isuckatwebdesign.com and see the layout and css using firebug.

RoR wouldn't cause an issue like this would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
#content { /* remove height: 110% */ overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Thanks @mdmullinax that was actually only part of the solution, i had the height to to 110% just to force it to fit for now, turns out i needed to change height to min-height: 100% and use overflow:hidden; thank for your help

I wouldn't have known about the overflow fixing the issue with out your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the content div to have a specific height, you just want it to wrap whatever is inside of it, regardless of how many pages that content might go on for.
So, remove your height declaration in your CSS, and add the following to your HTML, just after the right column div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

This will force the content div to wrap around the div's it contains.  You can of course give this div an id and define the style in your CSS file, rather than inline.

Comment: I want the page to stretch all the way to the foot of the page, if someone has a monitor turned so it's taller vertically like have for my set up, it stretches to the bottom of the page on my current setup, if i don't define a min-height there is a blank space in between the end of the div and the end of the page.

Thank you for the help though, i might switch to that later on but right now id like the page to stretch all the way to the bottom at this time.

unless there is something fundamentally wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: No, I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with your use case / design.  I just misunderstood that part of the requirement.  Good luck!